# Blogspot post export to PDF

Tags: pdf, blogger

I need to read my own blog post that I published in Blogspot a long time ago.

How do I export my Blogspot post to PDF? So that I can read it in any places that don't have internet connection?

What I found when I searched for this was always about importing many posts into a book and usually their service is not free. I don't need to import many posts at once. I just need my one blog post.

Comment: Instead of converting it to PDF, you could use a service like [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/). [Read It Later](http://readitlaterlist.com/) and [Readability](http://www.readability.com/) are another two options.

Comment: @Alex, that doesn't answer my question. I need to read my post offline, preferably in PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to have a Print as PDF option on each of your blog posts for you & your readers, you can configure the service from [Web2PDF](http://savepageaspdf.pdfonline.com/getting_started/index.htm)

If it is just for yourself, you can turn to Chrome browser which now lets you print a page as PDF from the regular Print menu option.

NOTE: If you are using a Mac, almost any page can be printed to PDF by simply selecting "print" in the browser, then "Save as PDF" in the bottom right of most printer control panels that appear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose [pdf converter sdk](https://www.cnetsdk.com/net-pdf-library-sdk) to achieve this demand, I recommend CnetSDK this product, very easy to use, the conversion quality is quite high, you can download the trial version for free to test whether it meets your needs.